# Images in Image catalogue not been loaded/not found when loaded programmatically

Tags: ios, xamarin, assets

I am trying to manage a background image using an image catalogue I have added according to the article described at https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_images/displaying-an-image/

I am trying to load the image programmatically without success but if I drop an Image view onto my View Controller and insert the image using Xamarins UI it loads fine.

Build action of the json and images is set to ImageAsset.

Unsure where I am going wrong.

View Controller code

```
using Foundation;
using System;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using UIKit;

namespace Performance
{
    partial class VCLanding : UIViewController
    {
        public VCLanding (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();

            UIImageView testImageView = this.imgVwTest;
            UIImage testImagePreLoaded = UIImage.FromBundle ("backgroundimage");

            testImageView.Image = testImagePreLoaded;

//          try{
//              UIImage backgroundImage = UIImage.FromBundle("backgroundimage");
//              View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromPatternImage(backgroundImage);
//          }catch(Exception ex){
//              Console.WriteLine (ex.Message);
//          }

        }
    }
}
```

Folder structure of Resources:

[image]

Contents.json

[image]

Debugging result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the documentation listed above fails to mention that the Images themselves need to be marked as BundleResource (Json stays ImageResource) as far as I can see. Only through experimentation did I gets this to work by changing the Build Action of the images.

Creating a new Image set and then adding images via the Asset browser marks the images as ImageAsset by default, so you need to change them to BundleResource.

But..

Now that I have got past the above issue, images are loading fine except for the iPad Air 2. This seems to be using the @2x image and tiling it. Should it not stretch this image to fill the device screen or use the @3x image ?

The dimensions of my images are

```
@3x = 1242 x 2208
@2x = 750 x 1334
@1x = 768 x 1024
```

iPad Air 2 - Using the @2x version of image but tiles it to fill

[image]

iPad 2 - Using the @1x version of image and fills correctly

[image]